# Как грамотно усечь массив (PHP)

Tags: php, массивы

Есть большой многомерный массив. Ключи могут быть разные. Может быть и с десяток вложенности. Т. е. количество вложенности мы не знаем.

Нужно как-то пройтись по нему и усечь длину каждого элемента до 200 символов. 
Как красивее?

Comment: Из начально сформировать более удобный массив для данных

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохранить его как JSON на диске. Читая посимвольно, писать в новый файл. Когда открылись очередные кавычки, считать число символов, чтобы не больше 200 и прекращать писать, до следующих кавычек % )

Comment: и когда кавычка появится внутри строки данных все сломается

Comment: `\"` игнорировать, escape-последовательности не бить и т.п. Воообще, ответ – непонятая шутка.

Comment: И сломаемся на `\\"`

Comment: может, специфика задачи такова, что там ислючительно шестнадцатиричные цифры в строках ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯